# pager is not working on update of Views 7.x-3.7 to Views 7.x-3.8

Tags: views, updating

Hi i have recently update one of project and so views module also updated now views pagignation is not working (from views 7.x-3.7 to views 7.x-3.8 version)
any help appreciated 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had the same problem. Issue for me was Views 7.x-3.8 changes the file plugins/views_plugin_query_default.inc to move the following code from the execute function to the query function.

I fixed it using the following patch:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2276165

Comment: Awesome. Was it the patched that helped?

Comment: yes, i have applied patch #6. and it was starting to work. thanks again.

Comment: Brilliant. Could you mark my answer as the correct one please. It's my first ever answer here :)

Comment: actually i tried but i don't know how to do it. I also tried to vote this answer but i can't because i don't have sufficient reputation.

Comment: @bisw if got your answer and you can accept the answer no need of sufficient reputation. it present below the vote option.